# libpq-fe.h not found when running rake

Tags: ruby, git, postgresql, rake

I'm currently having an issue raking a swift postgresql git submodule. The error is as follows:

```
 $ rake                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

    [19:38:19]
checking for uuid/uuid.h in /usr/include/uuid,/usr/include/postgresql,/usr/local/include/postgresql,/opt/local/include,/opt/local/include/postgresql90,/opt/local/include/postgresql85,/opt/local/include/postgresql84,/sw/include... yes
checking for libpq-fe.h in /usr/include/postgresql,/usr/local/include/postgresql,/opt/local/include,/opt/local/include/postgresql90,/opt/local/include/postgresql85,/opt/local/include/postgresql84,/sw/include... no
checking for main() in -luuid... yes
checking for main() in -lpq... yes
creating Makefile
compiling adapter.c
compiling common.c
In file included from adapter.c:6:
In file included from ./adapter.h:7:
./common.h:11:10: fatal error: 'libpq-fe.h' file not found
#include <libpq-fe.h>
         ^
In file included from common.c:5:
./common.h:11:10: fatal error: 'libpq-fe.h' file not found
#include <libpq-fe.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [common.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
1 error generated.
make: *** [adapter.o] Error 1
rake aborted!
unable to compile postgres
/Users/Dan/Dropbox/My Documents/Programming/Mash/mash-ios/swift-db-postgres/Rakefile:33:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/Dan/Dropbox/My Documents/Programming/Mash/mash-ios/swift-db-postgres/Rakefile:32:in `chdir'
/Users/Dan/Dropbox/My Documents/Programming/Mash/mash-ios/swift-db-postgres/Rakefile:32:in `block in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => default => test => compile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I have checked that the file does exist at /usr/local/include/libpq-fe.h, and have tried including this in my build path, but the error persists. Uninstalling and reinstalling postgres has no effect. I'm thinking it may have to do with symlinks somewhere along the line, but have no idea how to tackle the issue. Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Make sure that `pg_config` is on your `PATH`. If you run `pg_config --help` what gets printed?

Comment: I included my pg_config at `/usr/local/bin/pg_config` in the `PATH`. My `pg_config --help` is the standard help output. Still throws the same error upon rake.